# Can we move lines in TextEdit?

Tags: macos, textedit

Using TextEdit is there a key board shortcut to move the current line up/down? (similar to how code editors like Sublime Text works)

Comment: To be succinct: No. BareBone's app [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) has this feature.

Comment: @IconDaemon - I feel sure this should be an answer [with appropriate fleshing-out], not a comment .

Comment: BBEdit is also $50..Sort of pricey for an editor. I know it does a lot but if you are just typing notes or memos or papers it's pretty expensive.

Comment: Isn't there an emacs shortcut that could do this?  Emacs is not my editor of choice, so I am not fluent with it, but it seems like there would/could be one.

Comment: The cost is why I suggested BBE in a comment instead of an answer. If Imran writes code a for living, it may be worth the $.

Comment: The question is really geared towards TextEdit and whether this feature is available or not. I use other text editors for coding but I just want a super light weight text tool for writing todo lists.

Comment: BBEdit is free, only the advanced features need a license. I hate to snipe it as an answer, it really will help people as a proper answer, paid or not. https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/comparison.html

Comment: If you really want to do this in TextEdit, you could write an Applescript for it. Put the script into a TextEdit service via Automator, then assign the service to a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences. That you can add your own functionality to apps this way is something I really love about OS X.

Answer (score 2):

According to @IconDaemon there is no key combination to do this. A possible workaround is to select a word or phrase, or line that you want to move and while holding the mouse button down you can drag the selection elsewhere in the file.